# NSJSONSerialization fails on DBL_MAX

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I've run into a problem with deserialization of JSON containing a large double. Basically, I can serialize a dictionary like this

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"doubleVal": @DBL_MAX};
```

which serializes without trouble to

```
{"doubleVal":1.797693134862316e+308}
```

However, if I try to then deserialize the data, it blows up.

A small unit test that demonstrates the problem:

```
- (void)test_600_doubleJSON {
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"doubleVal": @DBL_MAX};
    NSError *jsonError, *jsonResponseError;

    NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&jsonError];
    id jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                      options:0
                                                        error:&jsonResponseError];

    STAssertNil(jsonError, @"JSON error: %@", jsonError.localizedDescription);
    STAssertNil(jsonResponseError,
                @"JSON response error: %@",
                jsonResponseError.localizedDescription);
}
```

The last assertion fails with the following:

```
JSON response error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)
```

If I replace `DBL_MAX` with a (much) smaller value, the test completes as expected.

Comment: The standard appear to be silent on rounding near boundaries.  However, your test should work for DBL_MAX - delta (where delta is maybe 1.0e+305).  If not then NSJSONSerialization is broken.  (Wouldn't be the first bug found.)

Comment: If there are issues with `DBL_MAX` and you don't also need `DBL_MIN` then perhaps you can use `[NSNull null]` as a special indicator of "no value" or "max value".

Comment: @HotLicks It seems to work starting around 1.0e+127, so not very near the boundary at all.

Comment: I'd suggest you file a bug report, if it's important to you.  And you can of course try one of the other (open source) Objective-C implementation -- there are 2-3 that are quite stable.  We've used JSONKit with very good luck.

Comment: I'm observing the same problem in our App. The JSON is coming from a server with legacy code so its not easy to change/fix.  Have you discovered a work around for the problem?  Did you file a bug report with Apple?  I have confirmed our Android app does not have the same issue.